# How to extend TYPO3 TCEforms image with a new field (column)?

Tags: typo3, typo3-tca, typo3-12.x

I'm using TYPO3 **12.4.6**

I want to add an extra **Subtitle** attribute (input field) beside the existing Title to the  **Image** element and I want to store it into the **sys_file_reference** table.

The following image contains the Image element, which should be extended with the new attribute:

[image: Existing Image form element]

I've already tried to to do it using **ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns**, and **ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes** , but it isn't working. The full code I wrote:

```
<?php

defined('TYPO3') or die();

$fields = [
    'subtitle' => [
        'label' => 'Subtitle',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'eval' => 'trim'
        ]
    ]
];


\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('sys_file_reference', $fields);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
    'sys_file_reference',
    'subtitle',
    '',
    'before:crop'
);
```

So, to repeat the question:
How can I add new input filed/attribute to the existing Image element?

Comment: I think it's easiest to add the it to the image palette instead. Use addTCAcolumns to add the column, and then addFieldsToPalette to add it to the imageoverlayPalette. And don't forget ext_tables.sql.

Comment: TCA is cached. Did you clear the cache. And you need the SQL statement to save it in database. Did you see your field in TCA array with module «Configuration»? Where is that code saved? What did not work?

Answer (score 0):

As the `crop` field is not listed in `showitem` of any type your insertion with `before:crop` is not specific.

You can find the `crop` field listed in the palette `imageoverlayPalette`. Though you should add your field to that palette:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette(
   'sys_file_reference',
   'imageoverlayPalette',
   'subtitle',
   'after:title'
);
```

(`after:title` as there is a `--linebreak--` between the fields `title` and `crop` and your field belongs more to the text-fields than to the button)

Answer (score -1):

Where have you defined the property for that field? I'm pretty sure you need one and of course a partial for that property to be able to render it. Can